# How do I solve this 'lights-on' puzzle?

Tags: obduction

I'm confronted with the following:

[image]

I can get all the lights on apart from one, which I can't get to light at all. Am I even trying to do the right thing?

What I've done so far:

> I've watered the tree in the main world, I've started and connected all the machinery next to this box, I've started the machinery at the other end too. I haven't worked out how to extinguish the red beam in this world.

Comment: I was cursing that number 5 for a good twenty minutes. And realizing the same Russian letter was on three different buttons made my head spin. Cyan brings the pwnage again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It isn't a puzzle, it's a joke in that it's a red herring for over-complicated puzzles in past Cyan games.

Double spoiler:

> There is an achievement later for destroying it that refers to it as the "Box of Infinite Complexity".

Comment: I've never been trolled so hard by a game before...

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling with that puzzle too. So while I can't be much help with that, I havended disabled the red beam in this world (Kaptar).
Hint: There's a sphere near the red beam that can be teleported back to Hunrath. You can pick up with you need there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer to this puzzle and it is not needed to complete the game. The best you can do with it is enter the 20 digit number you will find in the lower level on a table. If you enter this number while the stairwell is down and the box is held high up, it will come crashing down smash on the rocks and a few wires will pop out. You can also enter some codes you find online and get some Easter eggs.